# What is the difference between a qualifier and a modifier in C?

Tags: c

I would like to know the difference between a qualifier and a modifier. Some books suggest that `volatile` is a modifier, other books regard it as a qualifier.

So what is exactly a modifier and a qualifier, in respect to a variable?

Comment: Bonus question: Where does "declaration specifier" fit here?

Comment: @Kos: "a declaration specifier" is a more general category. There's actually no such thing as singular "declaration-specifier" in the C grammar, but "declaration-specifiers" is the list of storage class specifiers (`typedef`, `static`, `extern`, `auto`, `register`), type qualifiers (`const`, `restrict`, `volatile`), function specifiers (`inline`) and type names that (informally) say what the thing being defined actually is.

Comment: Ask the author of the book, they made up the term "modifier" out of the blue. There is no such term.

Answer (score 7):

In the C terminology `volatile` is a *qualifier*.

`const`, `restrict`, `volatile` and C11 `_Atomic` are the C type qualifiers.

C terminology does not use the word *modifier* when declaring an object.

Comment: Whats your take on storage classes ,are they also comes under qualifier?

Comment: `static` and `extern` are storage class specifiers, not qualifiers. One difference is that they're used in definitions only, while qualifiers can be used in declarations.

Comment: @ugoren: there's no such distinction in the syntax, though. It's just that various parts of the standard state that pretty much any object declaration with a storage class specifier is a definition, one way or anther (because it's an automatic, or because it's a tentative definition, or because it's an external definition, or possibly other kinds of definition I haven't thought of).

Comment: @SteveJessop, maybe I'm using the terms definition and declaration inaccurately. What I tried to say is that storage class specifiers apply when allocating memory for an object. Qualifiers apply for pointers to an object, regardless of how this object was allocated.

Comment: I see what you mean, yes. There's no such thing as pointer-to-extern or pointer-to-static, a pointer doesn't "know" what storage class its referand has. But there are such things as pointer-to-const and pointer-to-volatile, those are properties of the "type itself", and a pointer of course does need to "know" the type of the referand.

Comment: A text search through the C11 standard verifies this answer. There is nothing in the C language called "modifier". There is something called "length modifiers" in C, but that is the formal term for the letters `l, ll, L` etc in the print/scanf functions. Which of course is completely unrelated to volatile.