# Qualifiers, modifiers, specifiers

Tags: c, standards

So I have come across following definition in one of Wikipedia articles (rough translation):

> ***Modifier (programming)*** - element of source code being a phrase of given programming language construct, which results in changed behavior of given construct.

Then, the article mentions ***modifiers*** in regard to ANSI C standard:

> *type modifiers* (sign - `signed` `unsigned`, constness `const`, volatility `volatile`)

Then it also mentions the term in regard to languages such as Turbo C, Borland, Perl, but given there is no mention of ***modifier*** in [ANSI/ISO 9899](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), this already puts validity of article into doubt.

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360352/what-is-the-difference-between-a-qualifier-and-a-modifier-in-c) draw similar conclusions.

**However**, when looking at some of the top searches on google, you get the term ***modifier*** mentioned everywhere around in tutorial sections, or even example interview questions.

So the question is: Can the usage of the term **modifier** in this context be justified or rather requires correction when mentioned?

Comment: There are no "type modifiers" in the C standard. `unsigned`, `signed` are types of its own right and `const` is a qualifier. And don't cite Wikipedia for language-lawyer questions. Not sure how that is related to C. You already noticed it does not apply. Use standard terms. Perl is not C, Turbo-/Borland-C is a long time outdated, non-standard C compiler. No sure what your problem is.

Comment: When ask questions with missleading/unclear or wrong terminology, ask for clarification or point out the error. After all, such "flaws" tell you a lot about the asker (and that's nothing positive).

Comment: This is not only a problem of Wikipedia but also various resources on the internet, interview questions or academic assignments mentioning the term ***modifier***

Comment: I wrote a second comment about that one. Nevertheless is your question OT here. Not sure what your position is, but I don't accept such unclear terms and ask for clarification (first action) or leave the room (worst case scenario). Wibbly-wobbly has nothing to do in a professional environment.

Comment: It sounds like the Wikipedia article is not specifically about C, but describing a general concept in programming. Any application to a specific language will just be approximate, because every language is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the usage of the term **modifier** in this context be justified or rather requires correction when mentioned?

The C spec does not use "modifier" with a specific definition.  It does discuss how things are modifiable, etc. and details the term *modifiable lvalue*, but nothing that ties to OP's concerns about `signed`, `unsigned`, `const`,  `volatile`.

In C, `const`, `volatile`, and `restrict` are *type-qualifiers*.

`signed`, `unsigned` are 2 of the *standard integer types*.

So the authoritative reference is silent on "usage of the term modifier".

---

Lacking a standard reference answer, it does make sense, when using the term **modifier**, to justify its context to avoid quibbling corrections.

Like many terms that span multiple languages, the reader needs to understand the terms are used loosely when applied so broadly.  Each computer language has and needs very precise terms.  When speaking C, best to avoid the term unless a generality is needed in context with other languages.